Linker error results in Protobuf library as undefined
I'm pretty new to C++ and CMake and I've been struggling with this issue for the past few days so I could really use some help. The issue I'm having is the linker error during the building process of a C++ project (Valhalla routing machine).  Following a segment of the error message:
ld: Undefined symbols:                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
  google::protobuf::Message::GetMetadataImpl(google::protobuf::MessageLite::ClassDataFull const&), referenced from:                                                                                                                     
      vector_tile::Tile_Value::GetMetadata() const in libvalhalla.a[196](tomtom.pb.cc.o)                                                                                                                                                        
      vector_tile::Tile_Feature::GetMetadata() const in libvalhalla.a[196](tomtom.pb.cc.o)                                                                                                                                                      
      vector_tile::Tile_Layer::GetMetadata() const in libvalhalla.a[196](tomtom.pb.cc.o)                                                                                                                                                        
      vector_tile::Tile::GetMetadata() const in libvalhalla.a[196](tomtom.pb.cc.o)   

The error is showing that the functions in the generated file from a proto schema using protoc is referring to Protobuf runtime library, but the linker is saying they're undefined symbols.
1. Library source file check
First, I tried following where the error message was pointing at to see if they're actually missing. In /opt/homebrew/Cellar/protobuf/27.0/include/google/message.h which is the header for the protobuf runtime library, The class class PROTOBUF_EXPORT Message : public MessageLite {  has a segment that shows:
protected:
  // Get a struct containing the metadata for the Message, which is used in turn
  // to implement GetDescriptor() and GetReflection() above.
  Metadata GetMetadata() const;
  static Metadata GetMetadataImpl(const ClassDataFull& data);

which means the header does have GetMetadataImpl.  I, then, checked to see if there is an implementation for it by using nm which is a tool in macOS to inspect the symbols in library files:
nm /opt/homebrew/Cellar/protobuf/27.0/lib/libprotobuf.27.0.0.dylib | grep "GetMetadataImpl"

This showed the following:
00000000001144b0 t __ZN4absl12lts_2024011613base_internal12CallOnceImplIZN6google8protobuf7Message15GetMetadataImplERKNS4_11MessageLite13ClassDataFullEE3$_0JEEEvPNSt3__16atomicIjEENS1_14SchedulingModeEOT_DpOT0_
0000000000112d4c T __ZN6google8protobuf7Message15GetMetadataImplERKNS0_11MessageLite13ClassDataFullE
00000000001692d4 s __ZZN4absl12lts_2024011613base_internal12CallOnceImplIZN6google8protobuf7Message15GetMetadataImplERKNS4_11MessageLite13ClassDataFullEE3$_0JEEEvPNSt3__16atomicIjEENS1_14SchedulingModeEOT_DpOT0_E5trans

which seems to suggest that the precompiled binary of the Protobuf library libprotobuf indeed contains the implementation of GetMetadataImp.
2. Compiler and library compatibility check
Second, I checked to see if the protoc compiler and the Protobuf runtime library have incompatible versions as they both have to be compatible to each other, but they showed libprotoc 27.0 and protobuf 27.0.  I even tried 26.1 version for both, but still got the same linker error.
By the way, I found at the top of the generated header from proto using protoc following condition check:
#if PROTOBUF_VERSION != 5027000
#error "Protobuf C++ gencode is built with an incompatible version of"
#error "Protobuf C++ headers/runtime. See"
#error "https://protobuf.dev/support/cross-version-runtime-guarantee/#cpp"
#endif

which seems to indicate that the version 5.27 for the Protobuf library should be used, but the error did not get triggered during the build process so not sure if this is relevant. To be frank, I did try to install the version 5.27 of protoc and libprotobuf, but only protoc seems to exist and not the library.
3. Library to project link check
Third, I tried to see if the Protobuf library is properly linked to Valhalla the main project. Following is a segment of CMakeLists.txt at the root directory of the project:
# Protobuf is non-trivial to include via pkg-config, pkg_check_modules has no way to check
# for protoc location in a platform agnostic manner
# newer protobuf versions require a compat bool
set(protobuf_MODULE_COMPATIBLE ON CACHE BOOL "")
find_package(Protobuf REQUIRED)
# and turn it off again
message(STATUS "Using protoc from ${Protobuf_PROTOC_EXECUTABLE}")
message(STATUS "Using pbf headers from ${Protobuf_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
message(STATUS "Using pbf libs from ${PROTOBUF_LIBRARIES}")
if(TARGET protobuf::libprotobuf-lite)
  message(STATUS "Using pbf-lite")
endif()
if(TARGET protobuf::libprotobuf-lite)
  set(valhalla_protobuf_targets protobuf::libprotobuf-lite)
elseif(TARGET protobuf::libprotobuf)
  set(valhalla_protobuf_targets protobuf::libprotobuf)
else()
  message(FATAL_ERROR "Required target protobuf::libprotobuf-lite or protobuf::libprotobuf is not defined")
endif()

Logging above during the build process shows the following:
-- Found Protobuf: /opt/homebrew/bin/protoc-27.0.0 (found version "27.0.0")                                                                                                                                                                     
-- Using protoc from /opt/homebrew/bin/protoc-27.0.0                                                                                                                                                                                            
-- Using pbf headers from /opt/homebrew/include                                                                                                                                                                                                 
-- Using pbf libs from /opt/homebrew/lib/libprotobuf.27.0.0.dylib                                                                                                                                                                               
-- Using pbf-lite

Which seems to indicate that both protoc and libprotobuf are being properly located and that they have matching versions.  However, nowhere in the rest of the project mentions valhalla_protobuf_targets or libprotobuf (except for one other place which I'll mention later) so I'm not sure if above code is only for logging purposes and not actually linking it to the targets, which led me to try adding it to the project target, although the same linker error persisted:
if(ENABLE_TOOLS)
  foreach(program ${valhalla_programs})
    get_source_path(path ${program})
    add_executable(${program} ${path})
    set_target_properties(${program} PROPERTIES FOLDER "Tools")
    create_source_groups("Source Files" ${path})
    target_link_libraries(${program} valhalla ${valhalla_protobuf_targets})
    target_include_directories(${program} PRIVATE ${cxxopts_include_dir})
    install(TARGETS ${program} DESTINATION "${CMAKE_INSTALL_BINDIR}" COMPONENT runtime)
  endforeach()
endif()

In cmake/ValhallaPkgConfig.cmake, The protobuf library seems to be being added to REQUIRE:
  if(TARGET protobuf::libprotobuf-lite)
    list(APPEND REQUIRES protobuf-lite)
  else()
    list(APPEND REQUIRES protobuf)
  endif()

Although, I'm not sure what to make of it. If you look back to beginning, the linker error does make a reference to libvalhalla.a which is a pkg-config file.

I don't know anything about protobuf but this looks wrong to me: set(valhalla_protobuf_targets protobuf::libprotobuf).  Since you use this variable to add to the target link libraries: target_link_libraries(${program} valhalla ${valhalla_protobuf_targets}) that means the variable valhalla_protobuf_targets should be set to the name of the protobuf library that needs to be linked in; the value protobuf::libprotobuf is no valid library name I've ever seen before.

But, maybe that's how the protobuf cmake package works?  Dunno.

hmm.. could you recommend a different way?

What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?

Sorry, but it all depends on what the protobuf CMake integration looks like and I don't know that.  Maybe the protobuf documentation has an example of how to use the cmake integration.  Else you'll have to wait for a protobuf person to respond.  Basically the problem is that your link command is not listing the protobuf library in the link line.  You need to add the protobuf library as a prerequisite via target_link_libraries but in order to do that you need to know what the name of that target library is, that is created by the protobuf cmake integration.

Run make with additional option VERBOSE=1. That way it will print the exact command line executed. Inspecting given command line should be the first step when debug linker errors (and when you are unsure whether the required library is actually passed to the linker).

"However, nowhere in the rest of the project mentions valhalla_protobuf_targets ..." - The variable is actually used: https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Avalhalla%2Fvalhalla%20valhalla_protobuf_targets%20&type=code

@Tsyvarev thank you for pointing out that valhalla_protobuf_targets is being used elsewhere. I clarifies some confusion I had. Also, I tried with VERBOSE=1 and I was able to find out that the project is linking against libprotobuf-lite when libprotobuf is being provided. So I think you might have resolved this particular error.

" I was able to find out that the project is linking against libprotobuf-lite ... " - This is what CMake tells too: -- Using pbf-lite.
